# “J'ai” or “j'ai eu”—is there a difference in meaning?

Tags: temps-grammatical, passé-composé

Which of these two sentences makes more sense?
J'ai mon permis de conduire OR J'ai eu mon permis de conduire?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The assertion is the same — You have a driving license —, since you can't have it without having got it, but the focus is different :

- « *J'ai eu mon permis de conduire* » puts emphasis on the obtainment of the driving license
- « *J'ai mon permis de conduire* » puts emphasis on the actual possession of driving license

For instance, you would answer « *J'ai eu mon permis de conduire* » if you were asked something like “Have you passed any examination?” and « *J'ai mon permis de conduire* » to “Are you in possession of any official document?”.

Comment: A non-literal translation could be something like "I **have** my driver's license" for "j'ai" and "I **got** my driver's license" for "j'ai eu".

Answer (score 4):

Take the verb *“danser”*, “to dance”. Its “indicatif présent” is *“je danse”* (“I dance” or ”I’m dancing”); its *indicatif passé composé* is *“j’ai dansé”* (“I danced”). *“Avoir”* appears here as *“ai”*, but the main verb still is *“danser”*.

In your case, the word *“eu”* is the past participle (singular masculine) of the verb *“avoir”*. Hence, *”j’ai”* is the *indicatif présent* of *“avoir”* and *“j’ai eu”* is its *indicatif passé composé*. In *“j’ai eu*”, *“ai”* is *“avoir” used as an auxiliary verb*. It’s only by chance that *“avoir”* also is the main verb.

So, if the sentence were translated with *“avoir”* with its meaning of “to possess”:

> *J'ai mon permis de conduire.* I have my driving license.
>   *J’ai eu mon permis de conduire.* I had my driving license. (I don’t have it anymore.)

However, *“avoir”* has *lots* of different meanings, one of which is “to obtain, to acquire“. And, without any contest, this meaning is much more likely in *“J’ai eu mon permis de conduire”*.

> *J’ai eu mon permis de conduire.* I got my driving license.

So *“J’ai mon permis de conduire”* puts the emphasis on the fact that you have your driving license; “J’ai eu mon permis de conduire” puts the emphasis on the fact the you obtained it.